# Java.nio Files.walk() Java 8 List and count All Files And Directories

Tags: java, foreach, stream

Using Java 8 with java.nio package. `Files.walk()` Java 8 Method will List All Files And Directories. Is there a way to count the number file and directories.

I have a solution using File and isDirectory() but I want to try to achieve the same result using Files.walk

This sample runs fine.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Java8ListFilesInDirectory 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Stream<Path> files = Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\temp"));   
        files.forEach(System.out::println);
        files.close();
    }
}
```

However I want to count the files/directories also and have tried

```
    { 
        int dirCount = 0;
        Stream<Path> files = Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\temp"));   
        files.forEach(System.out::println);
        files.forEach(dirCount++);
        files.close();
    }
```

but the java class fails to compile with

> error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Consumer files.forEach(dirCount++);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**

```
long dirCount = files.peek(System.out::println).count();
```

---

The `forEach` method requires a `Consumer` as it's parameter:

```
void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action);
```

Where the consumer has a contract of:

```
public interface Consumer<T> {
    void accept(T t);
    ...
}
```

So in order to satisfy the contract of `Consumer` you have to provide a method which takes a `T t` parameter.

In the first example you are using a method reference:

```
files.forEach(System.out::println);
```

`System.out::println` is able to satisfy the contract as it is defined as:

```
void println(Object obj);
```

In the second example, you do not provide an expression which can satisfy the parameter, it is just a statement. You might think *"Okay, I'll use a lambda that satisfies the contract to do this"* but that would also have errors:

```
files.forEach(file -> dirCount++);
// Fails to compile because dirCount is not final
```

For an object to be used inside a lambda from the outer scope then it must be final, meaning that you cannot change the reference or primitive value that variable points to. Another problem is that you can only iterate through the stream once. As soon as you iterate through it, then it will be empty.

So given the problem, I would solve this using `peek` and `count`. You can use `peek` to perform an action when each item comes through the stream and sends the value on to the next operator. After that `count` will evaluate how many items are in the stream (consuming the stream to do so):

```
long dirCount = files.peek(System.out::println).count();
```